# Why can I not use unlocked weapons in single-player campaign?

Tags: battlefield-4

I finished the first mission in BF4 with a Gold rating, and was supposed to receive the SVD-12. However, on the next mission, in the weapons crate, it's still not available.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that the only one that didn't unlock (if you got gold, there should be two other weapons)? Are you sure you didn't get bronze which you may have confused with gold?

Comment: I've replayed the mission and got the SVD-12 - it seems that it was a bug..